# NGINX Custom Rules for each user on their home

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, url-rewriting

I have running my web server with nginx, And having about 10 websites on it. I'm wondering if there's a way my users could put their custom rewrite rules like .htaccess(Apache) on the html directory of their websites.

Comment: Nope. There is no .htaccess analogy in nginx

Comment: @AlexeyTen Then maybe i have to use both apache and nginx as a reverse proxy behind the apache, Is this a good practice ? What do you think ?!